# NIS user not being added to NIS group

Tags: linux, nis

I have set up a NIS server and several NIS clients.  I have a user and a group on the NIS server like so:

```
/etc/passwd:  myself:x:5000:5000:,,,:/home/myself:/bin/bash
/etc/group:   fishy:x:3001:otheruser,etc,myself,moreppl
```

I imported the users and groups on the NIS client by adding `+::::::` to `/etc/passwd` and `+:::` to `/etc/group`.

I can log in to the NIS client, but when I run `groups`, *fishy* is not listed. But `getent group fishy` shows that it was imported correctly and lists me as a member.  And if I do `sudo su - myself`, then suddenly `groups` says I am in the group!

I also had `nscd` installed, and the groups worked correctly for a while.  It seemed like after being logged in for a while, I would silently be dropped out of the group. If I restarted `nscd` and logged in again, then the groups worked correctly...for a while.

There are no UID or GID conflicts with local users or groups.

**Update:** Contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files nis dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
aliases:        nis files
```

Comment: are you by any chance running [`nscd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/nscd), also known as "Ye wretched bane of my existence"?

Comment: I described the role of nscd in all of this in the second-to-last paragraph.  I was running nscd at first but uninstalled it to eliminate it as the cause.

Comment: So you did.... blind today I am!  Second question - "Do you have more than one NIS server?" (the behavior you're describing in that paragraph sounds like you may have a slave that isn't getting updates - assuming you're adding yourself to a group in an existing environment?)

Comment: What does your /etc/nsswitch file look like?  How many groups are you in total? There is a limit to the number of groups automatically initialized on many UNIX/Linux systems.

Comment: @mdpc, updated with /etc/nsswitch.conf.  What really confuses me is why my NIS groups don't appear when I log in, but after `sudo su - myself` then they do.  Seems like bad permissions on something, but I have no idea what...

Comment: @voretaq7, nope, just one NIS server; no slaves.

Comment: You might want to add the output from 'uname -a' and the contents of /etc/*release  .... and the output from 'id -a' BEFORE and AFTER you do the su to yourself.

Comment: Yup, ncsd was doing it for me, stop the daemon and the NIS groups show up, start it again and they disappear again. so I stopped nscd caching group in nscd.conf, restarted the daemon and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't remember where I found the solution for this, but I was able to solve it by adding "nis" to the "group" line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
passwd:         compat
group:          compat nis
shadow:         compat
```